# Sending data changed when it received

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have one textarea. I am sending the value of text area

```
<textarea class="php" name="codeguru"></textarea></div>
<div class="hint">This code is editable. Click Run to execute.</div>
<input type="submit" value="Run" />
```

through $ajax method

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'exec.php',
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    data: {
        code: code
    },
    success: function (data) {},
    jsonpCallback: 'mycallback',
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError, err, textStatus) {

    }
});
```

Problem : When i am send a data like echo 'sanjay';
it is converted to echo \'sanjay'.

I have same implemented it on localhost and on cpanel. This works fine on localhost but not perfectly on cpanel. Any suggestions or ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `magic_quotes_gpc` enabled in your `php.ini`? http://www.php.net/magic_quotes

Comment: try var_dump(get_magic_quotes_gpc()), if you got ture, then magic_quotes_gpc is the problem.

Comment: `magic_quotes_gpc` is removed as of php 5.4.0, so If you're above that no need to check. Source: http://www.php.net/magic_quotes

Answer (score 3):

I got my answer

```
$code = stripslashes($code);
```

Because of this code i am able to remove blackslashes

Answer (score 0):

You should URL Encode it before the AJAX and decode it server side.
This happens alot to me with specific chars in JSON strings, I usually URL encode it :

Meaning :

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'exec.php',
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    data: {
        code: encodeURIComponent(code)
    },
    success: function (data) {},
    jsonpCallback: 'mycallback',
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError, err, textStatus) {

    }
});
```

And in server side :

```
$code = urldecode($_POST['code']); // or rwaurldecode, not sure
```

Try sending code with `/` and `"` and see how it responds, because I had issues with those as well, if it does try adding slashes to quotes, etc. I use the following function, but you can modify it to suit your needs :

```
function addslashes( str ) {
    return (str + '').replace(/[\\"]/g, '\\$&').replace(/\u0000/g, '\\0');
}
```

Comment: i had tried your code but not working. If i have to change my code after recieving then what i have tod like i am recieving this code echo \'sanjay' now i want to change to echo 'sanjay' so what should i do?

Comment: You shouldn't receive echo \'sanjay', if you encode it before sending, and do check about the magic quotes.